# Synthetic of kotlin extensions does not work when I import Android-ktx in gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I'm trying to test some android jetpack features in my project, I already have the navigation working. When I tried to import android-ktx and migrate my dependencies to androidx I managed to synchronize the gradle successfully, but I lost access to my button through synthetic.

Anyone have any idea what it can be?

My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qmakercorp.qmaker"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
//    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-beta01'

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0-beta01' 

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
```

My Fragment:

[image: Print from fragment]

Comment: invlidate caches/restart may help

Answer (score -1):

In your app `build.gradle` file you imported `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0` and clicked `Sync Now`. After that you had error saying `Manifest merger failed : Attribute bla bla ...` and commented `com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0` but there wasn't shown `Sync Now` and you didn't sync your project with gradle files. That's way you still able to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from `LoginFragment`. 
Suggestion: click `Sync Project with Gradle Files` button 
and replace `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21355695)

Comment: @mmvsbg yes, it does (even before edit). "try to do X" is enough to pass as an answer

Comment: Suggestions should be written as comments, not answers. Your original answer also did not have any explanation of what is the problem and why one should try the code that you suggested.